# Something like de-lambdify

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Suppose I have the following lambda function

```
import numpy as np
f = lambda x,t : np.cos(t)
```

Now I want to obtain a symbolic expression of f (the ultimate goal is to obtain a primitive of that function f). So

```
import sympy as sym
x_s = sym.Symbol('x')
t_s = sym.Symbol('t')
sym.integrate(f(x_s,t_s), t_s)
```

But that fails with the error:

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol
>   which has no callable cos method

I want to be able to translate any Closed-form expression to sympy.

Thanks.

Edit: What I am trying to achieve at the end is to numerically solve a PDE using Dedalus. For the moment I just need a linear reaction diffusion equation with non-constant coefficients. That function f(x,t) is one of the coefficients. Since the equation is linear, I have the analytic solution, which is a function that depends on the primitive with respect to t of that function f(x,t). So I want to input the function f(x,t) in one place, and then use it to construct the numerical solution (in this case I just need to call the f(x,t) and also the analytic solution (in this case I need to call the primitive of f(x,t)).

So bottom line:
I need to define a lambda function that depends on 2 arguments x and t for the following purpose:

1) compute values given x and t.
2) convert that function definition to text to be used to solve the numerical equation using dedalus (and replace every reference to sym to np, otherwise dedalus will give error).
3) be able to obtain the primitive of that function (that's why I am using sympy) and then define a lambda function of that primitive in order to compute values for getting the analytical solution.

Comment: When you pass `Symbols` to a `numpy` function, it wraps it in an object dtype array.  Math with such an array is hit-or-miss.  It depends on what methods the Symbol has.  `__add__` is ok, `cos` and `exp` are not.  Mixing `sympy` and `numpy` is iffy.  Don't confuse the Python `lambda` (just a variant on function `def`), with `sympy.lambdify`.

Comment: Thanks. I know the coding is a bit odd, but I've started with python 2 days ago. What suggestion do you have?

Comment: Mixing the 2 packages is tricky even for an experienced python jser.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you simply want to write functions that work with symbolic expressions as input? Or do you want to be able to dissect arbitrary functions? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because numpy`s cos is not compatible with sympy.Symbol. To get rid of this error you should rewrite your lambda like this:

```py
import sympy as sym
f = lambda x,t : sym.cos(t)
```

De-lambdify is performed like this:

```py
x_s = sym.Symbol('x')
t_s = sym.Symbol('t')
sym.integrate(f(x_s,t_s), t_s)
```

When you call f, it returns sympy cos function.
P.S. Check if you really need x parameter in f function.
So, full code will be:

```py
import sympy as sym

f = lambda x,t : sym.cos(t)
x_s = sym.Symbol('x')
t_s = sym.Symbol('t')
sym.integrate(f(x_s,t_s), t_s)
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get this error: "NameError: name 'sym' is not defined" , despite sym is defined.

Comment: It’s very strange, can you show full code of your try? I used exactly this code and it worked.

Comment: Probably if you copied my code, the problem is with encoding of some symbols, try to type code by hands.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Your code works perfectly. I apologize for that. I was getting that error on a step after that. And it is the following: Now I need to define a lambda function with the primitive of f. So I defined intf = sym.lambdify((x_s,t_s),sym.integrate(f(x_s,t_s), t_s),'numpy')
I think the error is because the parameter of lambdift is 'numpy'. Thanks.

Comment: So bottom line: I need to define a lambda function that depends on 2 arguments x and t for the following purpose:

1) compute values given x and t. 2) convert that function definition to text to be used to solve the numerical equation using dedalus (and replace every reference to sym to np, otherwise dedalus will give error). 3) be able to obtain the primitive of that function (that's why I am using sympy) and then define a lambda function of that primitive in order to compute values for getting the analytical solution.

Comment: You should select the answer that helped you with check mark.

Comment: I did, but since I am new the score did not appear.

Comment: I mean not score, but selecting answer as a right and full one. You can do this with clicking grey check mark( not up and down buttons) . This helps other user who faced similar problem to find answer.